# Play multiple audio files with one click event howler js

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

Wordpress website.  Scripts enqueued etc. I was able to get a single audio file to play without the array.

After using this though...

```
(function( $ ) {
'use strict';

jQuery(window).load(function() {
    var sound_files = {
            sound1 : new Howl({
                src: ['/synthv2.mp3'],
                loop: true
            }),
            sound2 : new Howl({
                src: ['/synthv2.mp3'],
                loop: true
            }),
            sound3 : new Howl({
                src: ['/synthv2.mp3'],
                loop: true
            })
        };
    var play_button = $('#play-button'),
        pause_button = $('#pause-button'),
        shift_preset = $('#preset-changer'),

    play_button.click(function() {
        sound_files.play();
    });
});

})(jQuery);
```

I consistently get sound_files.play is not a function errors.

How can I trigger sound1, sound2, and sound3 all at the same time with a single button click?

Comment: That's because you haven't defined a function called `play` on `sound_files`. You need to either call `sound_files.sound1.play(); sound_files.sound2.play();` etc. or [iterate over the object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8312459/371184) and play them that way.

Comment: thanks mike...utilized your comment in conjunction with the link you provided and the code from FrankerZ.

Comment: can you add the complete solution also

Comment: Please see the approved answer below.  It's not a copy and paste type of wordpress fix, but a loop through audio declaration then js assign to the front end controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sound_files` is an object, so you can't simply call `.play()` on them.

You would need to loop through them, and play them all:

```
for (var prop in sound_files) {
    // skip loop if the property is from prototype
    if(!sound_files.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

    sound_files[prop].play();
});
```

Comment: nailed it...still learning, but very quick and easy concept to get

Answer (score 1):

or you could...

```
    var sound_files = {
        sound1 : new Howl({
            src: ['/synthv2.mp3'],
            loop: true
        }),
        sound2 : new Howl({
            src: ['/synthv2.mp3'],
            loop: true
        }),
        sound3 : new Howl({
            src: ['/synthv2.mp3'],
            loop: true
        }),
        play: function(){
            this.sound1.play();
            this.sound2.play();
            this.sound3.play();
        }
    };
```